# Register-ObjectEvent across computers

Tags: events, powershell-remoting, subscriptions, invoke-command

I'm trying to kick off an event subscription script in a remote box, which has the logic to subscribe to FileSystemWatcher 'file created' event locally. The script works fine locally. But when I execute it remotely from another machine (using invoke-command), nothing seems to be happening. In the target box, Get-EventSubscriber returns nothing.

Comment: Please share your code!

Comment: $fileWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$fileWatcher.Path = "C:\users\abc\desktop\filewatcher"

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $fileWatcher -EventName Created -SourceIdentifier File.Created -Action {
    $Global:t = $event
    Write-Host ("File Created: {0} on {1}" -f $event.SourceEventArgs.Name,
    (Split-Path $event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath))
}

Comment: when I run the above script in PS shell locally, I see the event getting created and doing what its supposed to do. But when I execute it from another box, the event is not created. Is subscription designed to run only though a shell and persist as long as the shell is active.

Comment: It's better to update the question with your script! Please use 'edit' link and then insert your script into your question statement.